# How to console log in couchdb

Tags: javascript, couchdb

First off I'm really loving all the things you can do with CouchDB.  I'm coming from a lot of front end JavaScript and I use console.log() for lots of debugging and testing tasks.  I'm wondering how to console.log or what a better way to debug might be in CouchDB.

Any suggestions would be really awesome!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CouchDB exposes a [`log`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Debugging_Views) method for debugging views. (presumably it also works for show, list, update and validation functions too) It sends output to the **couch.log** file on your system.

Comment: Hmmm...okay, and I think logging is also visible in the console where couch is running, if you're developing locally.  How do I call the method?

Comment: It isn't obvious where the link is. So: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Debugging_Views

Comment: where is couchdb.log file located ? can you give me the path?